# Two factor authentication - flow

Tags: authentication, google-authenticator

I'm sure this question applies to whatever TFA method you want to use....

I'm implementing google authentication on a site (asp.net C#) and can't quite get my head around the flow to provide the user with the QR or manual setup code.

My concern surrounds if a hacker knows/guesses an initial username/password, I can't show them the QR as they will be authenticated against a valid user.
Additionally, if a legit user logs in normally and sees the QR...but doesn't act on it at that time, I'd like to show them the code again as well as, if the given user has multiple devices (mobile, tablet, desktop) they want to set up GA auth on those devices... so a one time QR just won't work (although showing the same QR code would).

One thought I had was allow a user to log in normally (without TFA), and allow them to enable TFA. They see their setup QR code and we're good. Other devices can then be set up by logging in again (using the new TFA method) to get the code to add these extra devices.

Creating/validating the Auth code is not my problem, it's how to setup without risk of hackers getting the setup code. All demos I've found show people logging in and immdiately see the QR code, which if hacked is a weak point.

What's the correct flow/implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The QR code contains the secret key, which is used to generate one-time passwords (OTPs). The QR code is required only in process of token enrollment. User logins as usually (with his username and password, without 2FA), then if he would like he could enable 2FA, he’ll get the QR code (or the secret key). He could just save it in some safe place and if he needs - scans it by other devices (mobile, tablet, desktop) to generate OTPs. It isn’t required to show the QR code each time user login. In this case, 2FA loses its meaning.